# How to create threads in silverlight native c++?

Tags: c++, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to create thread in native C++, but it results in an error. I am trying to do it this way:

```
CreateThread(NULL,myfunction,NULL,0,NULL);
```

It shows wrong arguments error and I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: use C++'s standard threading library

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's really not necessary use unusual functions like this. Try to use std libraries.